# How to join two lines in one using select?

Tags: jquery, mysql, select

I have the select code:

```
select
    produto_licitacoes.descricao,
    case when produto_unidades.unidade_id = 15 then produto_unidades.saldo else 0 end saldo,
    case when produto_unidades.unidade_id = 15 then produto_unidades.qtd - produto_unidades.saldo else 0 end demanda,
    case when produto_unidades.unidade_id = 3 then produto_unidades.saldo else 0 end caf,
    produto_notas.lote,
    produto_notas.dataValidade,
    'S' as tipo
from
    produto_unidades
    join produto_notas on produto_notas.id = produto_unidades.produtoNota_id
    join produto_licitacoes on produto_licitacoes.id = produto_notas.produtoLicitacoes_id
    join classe_terapeuticas on classe_terapeuticas.id = produto_licitacoes.classeTerapeutica_id
where 
    (produto_unidades.unidade_id = 3 or produto_unidades.unidade_id = 15)
    and produto_licitacoes.tipoProdutos_id = 1
    and produto_unidades.saldo > 0
```

This return the results:

```
'CIMETIDINA 200MG, COMPRIMIDO', '0', '0', '590', '17F35I', '2019-05-30', 'S'
'CIMETIDINA 200MG, COMPRIMIDO', '400', '0', '0', '17F051', '2019-05-30', 'S'
```

The first line is `produto_unidades.unidade_id = 3`, and second is `produto_unidades.unidade_id = 15`.

How to join the two lines?

```
'CIMETIDINA 200MG, COMPRIMIDO', '400', '0', '590', '17F35I', '2019-05-30', 'S'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would to to turn your query into an aggregate query, and use conditionnal aggregation with `MAX` to compute the variable fields. This requires adding a `GROUP BY` clause that lists all non-aggregatead fields :

```
select
    produto_licitacoes.descricao,
    max(case when produto_unidades.unidade_id = 15 then produto_unidades.saldo else 0 end) saldo,
    max(case when produto_unidades.unidade_id = 15 then produto_unidades.qtd - produto_unidades.saldo else 0 end) demanda,
    max(case when produto_unidades.unidade_id = 3 then produto_unidades.saldo else 0 end caf),
    produto_notas.lote,
    produto_notas.dataValidade,
    'S' as tipo
from
    produto_unidades
    join produto_notas on produto_notas.id = produto_unidades.produtoNota_id
    join produto_licitacoes on produto_licitacoes.id = produto_notas.produtoLicitacoes_id and and produto_licitacoes.tipoProdutos_id = 1
    join classe_terapeuticas on classe_terapeuticas.id = produto_licitacoes.classeTerapeutica_id
where 
    produto_unidades.unidade_id in (3, 15)
    and produto_unidades.saldo > 0
group by 
    produto_licitacoes.descricao,
    produto_notas.lote,
    produto_notas.dataValidade
```

Other changes to your original query :

- the `OR` conditions on `unidade_id` can be expressed as an `IN` condition
- moved a few join conditions from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause of the relevant `JOIN`